# ECMAScript 6: Можно ли в классе переопределить атрибуты тега?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Я хочу переопределить некоторые атрибуты результирующего тега по-умолчанию. Например, у меня есть компонент роутинга Link. Я хочу отнаследоваться от него и переопределить некоторые атрибуты тега по умолчанию. Как мне это сделать?

Сейчас код, который я написал выглядит так:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import styles from './CommonStyles';

class MyLink extends Link
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        // можно ли как-то здесь переопределить атрибуты результирующего тега?
    }

    render ()
    {
        return super.render();
    }
}

export default MyLink;
```

Хочу получить такой результат:

```
'use strict';

import {Link} from 'react-router';
import styles from './CommonStyles';

<Link style={styles.title} to="/" activeStyle={styles.active}>
    <p>Это какой-то текст ссылки</p>
</Link>
```

Comment: Но зачем? Я сам вторую неделю пишу на реакте, но сама затея кажется мне какой-то стремной. Компоненты должны быть минимальными и простыми, и если это так, наверное проще переписать рендер целиком чем вызывать super.render() и городить костыли.

Comment: Может дело просто в том, что я не знаю, как это сделать. Речь идет о компоненте из react-router. Вот об этом: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/Link.js Он выглядит каким-то чересчур сложным. Вроде, проще именно отнаследоваться.

Comment: идеальный компонент с точки зрения react - иммутабельный. лучше переопределить или обернуть.

Comment: А что **конкретно** вы хотите переопределить?

Comment: Вы хотите создать свой комонент MyLink, который базируется на Link, при этом MyLink уже будет в себе включать стили по умолчанию, которые будут передаваться в Link? Для того, чтобы для каждого использования MyLink не передавать вручную стили?

Comment: @MichaelRadionov, да, именно так. Я что-то делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд гораздо проще будет переиспользовать `Link` в рендере `MyLink`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import styles from './CommonStyles';

function MyLink(props) {
    return (
        <Link
            {...props}
            style={styles.title}
            activeStyle={styles.active}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Link>
    );
}

export default MyLink;
```

Используется чистая функция, т.к. кроме рендера от этого компонента больше ничего не нужно.

Аттрибутам `style` и `activeStyle` установлены значения по умолчанию.

`{...props}` нужен для того, чтобы из родителя передавать дополнительные аттрибуты прямо в `Link`, например такие как `"to"` либо любые другие, поддерживаемые компонентом `Link`.

`{props.children}` - вставка дочерних элементов `MyLink` внутри `Link`.

Пользоваться `MyLink` можно так:

```
<MyLink to="/">
    <p>Это какой-то текст ссылки</p>
</MyLink>
```

Если из родителя также хочется дополнять/переопределять стили по умолчанию `Link`, то это можно сделать через их расширение:

```
function MyLink(props) {
    return (
        <Link
            {...props}
            style={Object.assign({}, styles.title, props.style)}
            activeStyle={Object.assign({}, styles.active, props.activeStyle)}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Link>
    );
}
```

И использование:

```
<MyLink
    to="/"
    style={{ color: 'red' }}
    activeStyle={{ color: 'blue' }}
>
    <p>Это какой-то текст ссылки</p>
</MyLink>
```

Стили тогда будут смержены, а не полностью перезаписаны.

В ECMAScript 6 стиле это выглядит так:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router';
import styles from './CommonStyles';

class MyLink extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <Link
                {...this.props}
                style={styles.title}
                activeStyle={styles.active}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </Link>
        );
    }
}

export default MyLink;
```

Comment: к сожалению, это не работает. И я не понимаю, чем это принципиально отличается от расширения класса Link?

Comment: Ааа, понял, нужно в обратной последовательности. Сначала props передать, а потом уже засетить атрибуты. Исправил для большей достоверности.